# Applescript: Edit bookmark.plist file with new URL

Tags: applescript, plist

```
set some_host to "test.mydomain.com"

try
    -- Ping the host.
    do shell script "ping -c 1 -t 1 " & some_host
    -- Set ipAddr.
    set ipAddr to word 3 of result
    -- Combine the IP with the URL & port.
    set urlAddr to "http://" & ipAddr & ":80"
    display dialog "Connection Successful. " & urlAddr buttons {"OK"} default button 1
on error
    -- if we get here, the ping failed
    display dialog "Conection failed. " & some_host & " is down" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    return
end try

-- Update the URL with the new IP.
tell application "System Events"
    tell property list file "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist"
    set value of property list item "key" to text of urlAddr
    end tell
end tell
```

**Here's the error I get.** I should mention that "key" would be replaced with the bookmarks name I'm trying to change.

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t set property list item \"key\" of property list file \"~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist\" to \"http://000.000.000.000:80\"." number -10006 from property list item "key" of property list file "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist"
```

Bookmark.plist example: So lets replace "Key" with "NVR Camera"

```
<dict>
        <key>URIDictionary</key>
        <dict>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>NVR Camera</string>
        </dict>
        <key>URLString</key>
        <string>https://12.123.456.789:88</string>
        <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
        <string>WebBookmarkTypeLeaf</string>
        <key>previewText</key>
        <string>your description</string>
        <key>previewTextIsUserDefined</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

I'm trying to do this to update the URL automatically to the new IP if it changes. If anyone has a better solution I'm all ears! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the complete and real XML output for just that bookmark? Also, what version of OS X/macOS are you using?

Comment: Re: High Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Property List Data vs. XML Data

Here's an extract of my *Safari* **bookmarks.plist** file:

```
    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">
    <plist version=\"1.0\">
    <dict>
        <key>Children</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>History</string>
                <key>WebBookmarkIdentifier</key>
                <string>History</string>
                <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
                <string>WebBookmarkTypeProxy</string>
                <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
                <string>92E8B75A-B335-4CA3-8DE9-08A09817792D</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Children</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>ReadingListNonSync</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>neverFetchMetadata</key>
                            <false/>
```

That's just the first 24 lines, in which a tag with the label `<key>` has cropped up 8 times--roughly once every three lines.  You can imagine why AppleScript would get a bit confused when told to fetch the tag called `"key"` when there are so many.

Having said that, that isn't why your script threw the error.  I ran this command in *Script Editor*:

```
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        tell the property list file ¬
            "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.copy.plist" to ¬
            get every property list item whose name is "key"
```

(I'm using a copy of my bookmarks.plist file, because it's not out of AppleScript's capabilities to completely screw up any .plist file it reads from or writes to.)

The output from that command was: `{}`, which tells us that there are no property list items labelled `key`.

Although the plist file looks like XML, the way the data are handled by AppleScript is different to that of an XML file.  With an XML file, you reference elements using the name of its tag, such as `<key>`.  With a property list file, elements are referenced in key/value pairs, so that, where a `<key>` tag in XML data would have a **value** denoted by the name `"key"`, for a plist, it will contain the **name** of the property whose value will immediately follow.

For example:

```
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>History</string>
```

With XML data in AppleScript, we'd have two XML elements: one called `"key"` with the value `"Title"`; and the other called `"string"`, with the value `"History"`.  With plist data, we have but a single property list key/value pair (item), with the name `"Title"` whose value is `"History"`.

Going back to my initial point that there are, indeed, multiple tags with the same name; there are, likewise, multiple key/value pairs with the same key, and quite possibly, the same value.

Therefore, whether you handle the data as XML or as a property list, it's **always** necessary to tell AppleScript which level of the property list tree you are referencing.

#### AppleScripting

Which level of the hierarchy to reference depends entirely on where you want to store the bookmark: in a folder of its own; in the favourites folder or another folder that already exists; or just in the top-level of the bookmarks collection, so that it appears immediately in the list when you open the bookmarks side-bar.

For ease, I'll demonstrate the last option: adding a bookmark to the top-level of the folder tree.  I've marked below where in the plist file new entries are to be inserted:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Children</key>
        <array>
            <dict>...</dict>
            <dict>...</dict>
            <dict>...</dict>
            <!-- etc... //-->
            <dict>...</dict>
            <!-- insert new entry here //-->
        </array>
        <!-- other stuff //-->
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

If you run this command:

```
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        tell the property list file ¬
            "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.copy.plist" to ¬
            get the properties of the last property list item of ¬
                the property list item "Children"
```

AppleScript will return a **record**, which is its (lesser) attempt at storing data as key/value pairs.  It is basically an AppleScript list, where each entry in the list has a label that is used to reference the item instead of an index number.  The output returns looks like this (formatted for ease of reading):

```
     {value:{URIDictionary: ¬
         {title:"website.com"}, ¬
          previewText:"The title of the website", ¬
          ReadingListNonSync:{neverFetchMetadata:false}, ¬
          Sync:{ServerID:"DAV-DB576E16-E590-44D3-839F-63C0A1A8D3BC", ¬
               |data|:«a whole lot of data»}, ¬
          WebBookmarkUUID:"A5E4774A-2C26-4AD1-9938-D192C26860B8", ¬
          URLString:"https://website.com/path/etc", ¬
          WebBookmarkType:"WebBookmarkTypeLeaf", ¬
          previewTextIsUserDefined:true}, ¬
      kind:record, ¬
      class:property list item, ¬
      name:missing value, ¬
      text:"The XML representation of the property list data."}
```

This tells me what items make up a single bookmark entry in the plist file.  Bear in mind that, from AppleScript's point of view, each of those items is itself a `property list item`, so will need to be created individually as such.  I'm going to assume we can ignore `WebBookmarkUUID` and `sync`, both of which contain data we couldn't possibly generate ourselves.  The rest of them are easy, though.

#### Creating a New Bookmark Entry

```
    set urlAddr to "http://000.000.000.000:80"

    tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
        the property list file "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist" to tell ¬
        the property list item "Children" to tell ¬
        (make new property list item ¬
            at end of property list items ¬
            with properties {kind:record})

        make new property list item with properties ¬
            {name:"URIDictionary", kind:record}

        tell the result to make new property list item ¬
            with properties {name:"title", value:"mydomain.com", kind:string}

        make new property list item with properties ¬
            {name:"previewText", value:"Information about mydomain.com", kind:string}

        make new property list item with properties ¬
            {name:"URLString", value:urlAddr, kind:string}

        make new property list item with properties ¬
            {name:"WebBookmarkType", value:"WebBookmarkTypeLeaf", kind:string}

        make new property list item with properties ¬
            {name:"previewTextIsUserDefined", value:true, kind:boolean}

        make new property list item with properties ¬
            {name:"_tag", value:"AppleScript", kind:string}
    end tell

    return the result
```

Running this on my system successfully created a new bookmark entry called "mydomain.com", which, when clicked, tried to take me to the URL "http://000.000.000.000" (as per the dummy value of your `urlAddr` variable.

#### Updating the Bookmark

To update it each time you run your script, all you have to do is obtain a reference to the bookmark, and then a reference to the `property list item` that contains the information about the URL to which the bookmark points.

You'll notice that, above, I created a property list item called `_tag`, which the other bookmark entries do not have.  I did this so it would be easy to get the reference to bookmark by simply searching for the one that contains `_tag`:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
        the property list file "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.copy.plist" to tell ¬
        the property list item "Children" to ¬
        set bookmark to ¬
            the first property list item whose ¬
            name of property list items contains "_tag"
```

With the bookmark reference stored in the variable `bookmark`, updating the URL to which it points is done like this:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
        the property list file "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist" to tell ¬
        the property list item "Children"

        set bookmark to ¬
            the first property list item whose ¬
            name of property list items contains "_tag"

        set URLString to the first property list item ¬
            of bookmark whose name is "URLString"

        set the value of URLString to urlAddr
    end tell
```

### UPDATE:

Upon further testing and going back in to check the `bookmarks.plist` file following the changes committed through AppleScript, it emerges that *Safari* automatically **removes** the user-defined key `_tag`, which is a shame.  Conversely, it inserts `WebBookmarkUUID` and generates the value for it, which is great.

So, unfortunately, we can't use the method described above to tag our bookmark entry for easy referencing later.

This new script is, therefore, longer by necessity.  It's designed to replace the part of your script that starts with `tell application "System Events"`.

It will first check to see if a bookmark matching the specified `title` exists at the top level of the bookmarks hierarchy; if not, it will create it; if it does, it will update the address to which it points with whatever is contained in the variable `urlAddr`.

```
    set urlAddr to "http://google.com"
    set myTitle to "mydomain.com"
    set plistFile to "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist"


    tell application "System Events"
        tell ¬
            the property list file plistFile to tell ¬
            the property list item "Children" to ¬
            set top_level to a reference to it


        set bookmarks to a reference to ¬
            (property list items of the top_level ¬
                whose name of property list items ¬
                contains "URLString")

        set labels to ¬
            a reference to property list item "title" of ¬
                property list item "URIDictionary" of ¬
                property list items of ¬
                the bookmarks


        if the value of the result ¬
            does not contain myTitle then ¬
            return saveBookmark of me ¬
                for urlAddr ¬
                to plistFile ¬
                at a reference to property list items of the top_level ¬
                given |title|:myTitle, previewText:"your description"


        repeat with i from the number of bookmarks to 1 by -1

            if item i of ¬
                the value of the labels is ¬
                myTitle then ¬
                exit repeat

        end repeat

        set bookmark to item i of bookmarks
        set the value of ¬
            property list item "URLString" of ¬
            the bookmark to ¬
            the urlAddr
    end tell


    to saveBookmark for www as string ¬
        at locationRef ¬
        to plist as string : "~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist" given title:T ¬
        as string, previewText:_t as string : ""

        local www, locationRef, plist
        local T, _t


        tell application "System Events" to tell the property list file plist

            tell (make new property list item at end of locationRef ¬
                with properties {kind:record})

                tell (make new property list item with properties ¬
                    {name:"URIDictionary", kind:record}) to ¬
                    make new property list item with properties ¬
                        {name:"title", value:T, kind:string}

                make new property list item with properties ¬
                    {name:"previewText", value:_t}

                make new property list item with properties ¬
                    {name:"URLString", value:www}

                make new property list item with properties ¬
                    {name:"WebBookmarkType", value:"WebBookmarkTypeLeaf"}

                make new property list item with properties ¬
                    {name:"previewTextIsUserDefined", value:true}

            end tell
        end tell
    end saveBookmark
```

If your bookmark exists elsewhere in the bookmarks hierarchy (such as in a folder), it currently won't be found, and a new bookmark will be created a the top level.  I will leave you to use what I've demonstrated in this example script and perhaps implement a deeper traversal of the bookmarks folder tree.

If you have any questions or problems, leave a comment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: The _code_ under **UPDATE:** errors out with `error "The variable urlAddr is not defined." number -2753 from "urlAddr"` and even if adding the presumed `set urlAddr to "http://000.000.000.000:80"` it doesn't work properly if the bookmark is not in "Children" in the top of the hierarchy and overwrites valid data in another bookmark. IMO Unless the _code_ can find the proper target regardless of its hierarchal position, then it's a non-answer! You just cannot assume the target is directly under the first occurrence of `property list item "Children"` as their can be numerous occurrences of it.

Comment: @user3439894 I've updated the code now to be more robust.  It still only checks the top level of the hierarchy, which I have been explicit about in my prose.  It now first checks to see if a bookmark exists with a matching title (this is user-defined, so is up to the OP to make it distinct).  If no bookmark exists at the top-level (even if one might exist elsewhere), it creates a new bookmark at the top-level.  If a match is found, however, it then proceeds to update the URL to which it points.  I even deleted all of my own bookmarks to make sure it worked with zero existing entries.

Comment: "If your bookmark exists elsewhere in the bookmarks hierarchy (such as in a folder), it currently won't be found, and a new bookmark will be created a the top level. I will leave you to use what I've demonstrated in this example script and perhaps implement a deeper traversal of the bookmarks folder tree."  Such a shame! No +1 from me!

Comment: @user3439894 That's ok, I appreciate your alerting me to the problem earlier.  You have no idea how much time and effort has gone into this, I'm quite literally exhausted after hours of testing.  I agree it is a shame I am not choosing to go above and beyond, but I have answered/solved the OP's original problem, so I expect he'll be grateful for that at least.

Comment: @CJK First, thank you for such a detailed answer! I'm sure all those who follow will find it useful! My Bookmark is in fact in a folder, I suppose I could just move it to the top level to make this work. Although, you have to admit it defeats the purpose of organizing them to begin with. Not to mention it would be a great feat to have it work 100% no matter the location in the tree. That being said, I can't thank you enough for taking the time to provide the examples above. it will take me a bit of time to test and get it right with my setup, but I'm confident you have helped greatly!Thank you

Comment: @CJK I do have a question. Using text wrangler to find the bookmark, it gives a line number, can you use that as a tag? **~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist:3641:           <string>NVR Camera</string>**

Comment: @Jason I think I'm just a bit tired after concentrating on this for so long.  Tomorrow or the day after, I might be invigorated to take a fresh look at it and see if I can't provide you with a more universal solution.  After reading your kind thanks, it's given me the lift I need to believe I can do it.  I won't promise, but I'll see where I'm at in the next couple fo days.  Thanks for +1-ing and selecting my answer.  That definitely helps motivate me as well.  Best, CJK.

Comment: Re: *Text Wrangler*, I did consider treating the `plist` data as text, as there is a `text` AppleScript property that returns the content as an XML-formatted string.  But the difficulty with that would then be writing it back to the file, which is **not** text.  Locating the bookmark as text is actually very easy; it's getting the location reference in order to write it back to the file at the right place.  So, I'm not sure just yet.  I'll give it some thought.

Comment: Re: Thanks again, I know this took some time! I've spent a lot of time researching before posting here. It's slim pickins out there for something like this. You could be the first true answer! If that's not fuel for your fire, I don't know what would be! ha. If not I understand, I do appreciate what you have done here! People like you are what makes this site useful! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

After giving your issue some thought, I decided to take a different approach, without using **AppleScript**, and do it all directly in a `bash` shell *script*. This *script* can be used in **Terminal** (or in an **Automator** *service*, as well as other uses left to the User to implement).

The following is meant strictly as a *proof of concept* and is not necessarily robustly and or fully coded to meet every scenario explicitly. You are free to utilize it as you see fit, building upon the *proof of concept* shown herein.

I have tested the following *example* `bash` *code* under **macOS High Sierra** using it as a `bash` shell *script* in **Terminal** and as an **Automator** *service* without any unexpected issues.

This *script* is coded to act on the first *bookmark* containing **NVR Camera** regardless of where it exists in the hierarchal structure of the **Bookmarks.plist** file. If you have more then one *bookmark* for this *target*, the additional *bookmarks* for the same *target* will not be updated. As it's probably considered reasonable to only have one *bookmark* pointing to the same *target*, so this shouldn't be an issue. (That's not to say it can't be coded to handle more then one *bookmark* having the same *target*, I just didn't write it that way! Feel free to do so if you need it.)

This *script* can be run whether or not **Safari** is running, as it will dynamically update by replacing the **Bookmarks.plist** file if **Safari** is running. It was even tested with the **Bookmark Editor** opened, and one can see the **IP Address** update as if that was the only info changed in the original existing **Bookmarks.plist** file. In other words, it's a safe process.

---

As a plain `bash` shell *script*, open **Terminal** and execute the following commands:

```
touch UpdateIP; nano UpdateIP
```

In `nano`, copy and paste the *example* `bash` *code*, shown below changing `"google.com"` in `h="google.com"` to the proper *host name* for the `NVR Camera` to be used with the `ping` *command*.

Now save the `UpdateIP` file in `nano` by pressing the following keys:

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- <kbd>Y</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Back at the *command line*, make `UpdateIP` executable:

```
chmod u+x UpdateIP
```

Now execute `UpdateIP`:

```
./UpdateIP
```

---

*Example* `bash` *code*:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
# set -x

    # Host Name.

h="google.com"

    # Binary PLIST File.

bp="$HOME/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist"

    # XML File converted from Binary PLIST File.

bx="/tmp/Bookmarks.xml"

    # Get New Host IP Address.

nip="$(ping -c 1 -t 1 ${h} | grep -E -o -m 1 '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')"

    # Convert Binary PLIST File to XML File.

plutil -convert xml1 -o "${bx}" "${bp}"

    # Get Stored Host IP Address.

sip="$(grep -A3 -o 'NVR Camera' ${bx} | tail -1 | grep -E -o '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')"

    # Compare New Host IP Address against Stored Host IP Address.
    # If they do not match, then update the 'Bookmark.plist' file.

if [[ ! $nip == "$sip" ]]; then

    printf '  Host IP Address Did Not Match!\n  Updating Host IP Address...\n'

        # Backup Binary PLIST File.

    cp "${bp}" "${bp}$(date +.%m.%d.%Y_%H.%M.%S)"

        # Get line number containing the Host IP Address.

    ln="$(awk '/NVR Camera/{print NR+3; exit}' ${bx})"

        # Update Host IP Address in XML File.

    eval "sed -i -e ${ln}s#${sip}#${nip}# ${bx}"

        # Convert updated XML File to overwrite existing Binary PLIST File.

    plutil -convert binary1 -o "${bp}" "${bx}"

else

    printf '  Host IP Address Matched!\n'

fi
```

---

**Note:** The *example code* is just that and does not employ any explicit *error handling*, although with `set -e` enabled it will terminate execution if a error occurs, and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

---

The following **Terminal** *output* from the `UpdateIP` *command* is shown with `set -x` enabled in the *script* so as to show what it's doing when the **IP Address** needs updating:

```
$ ./UpdateIP
+ h=google.com
+ bp=/Users/me/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
+ bx=/tmp/Bookmarks.xml
++ ping -c 1 -t 1 google.com
++ grep -E -o -m 1 '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
+ nip=172.217.4.46
+ plutil -convert xml1 -o /tmp/Bookmarks.xml /Users/me/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
++ grep -A3 -o 'NVR Camera' /tmp/Bookmarks.xml
++ tail -1
++ grep -E -o '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
+ sip=172.217.30.20
+ [[ ! 172.217.4.46 == \1\7\2\.\2\1\7\.\3\0\.\2\0 ]]
+ printf '  Host IP Address Did Not Match!\n  Updating Host IP Address...\n'
  Host IP Address Did Not Match!
  Updating Host IP Address...
++ date +.%m.%d.%Y_%H.%M.%S
+ cp /Users/me/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist /Users/me/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist.03.06.2018_16.50.00
++ awk '/NVR Camera/{print NR+3; exit}' /tmp/Bookmarks.xml
+ ln=98121
+ eval 'sed -i -e 98121s#172.217.30.20#172.217.4.46# /tmp/Bookmarks.xml'
++ sed -i -e 98121s#172.217.30.20#172.217.4.46# /tmp/Bookmarks.xml
+ plutil -convert binary1 -o /Users/me/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist /tmp/Bookmarks.xml
$
```

Here the `UpdateIP` *command* is run again directly after to show the *output* when no update is required:

```
$ ./UpdateIP
+ h=google.com
+ bp=/Users/me/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
+ bx=/tmp/Bookmarks.xml
++ ping -c 1 -t 1 google.com
++ grep -E -o -m 1 '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
+ nip=172.217.4.46
+ plutil -convert xml1 -o /tmp/Bookmarks.xml /Users/me/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
++ grep -A3 -o 'NVR Camera' /tmp/Bookmarks.xml
++ tail -1
++ grep -E -o '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
+ sip=172.217.4.46
+ [[ ! 172.217.4.46 == \1\7\2\.\2\1\7\.\4\.\4\6 ]]
+ printf '  Host IP Address Matched!\n'
  Host IP Address Matched!
$
```

Without `set -x` enabled the *output* should show as follows, respectively:

```
$ ./UpdateIP
  Host IP Address Did Not Match!
  Updating Host IP Address...
$
```

And:

```
$ ./UpdateIP
  Host IP Address Matched!
$
```

Or if an error occurs, e.g. `ping` fails, or the *bookmark* doesn't exist:

```
$ ./UpdateIP
$
```

---

As an **Automator** *service*:

Create a new **Automator Service**, with the following settings:

- **Service receives [no input] in [Safari]**

Add a **Run Shell Script** *action*, with the following settings:

- **Shell [/bin/bash]**                **Pass input [to stdin]**

Replacing the *default code* with the *example* `bash` *code* shown above:

Save the **Automator Service**, then in **Safari**, select the *service* from the **Safari** > **Services** menu, and or you can add a keyboard shortcut for the *service* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **General**

Note that as an Automator *service*, as coded and also using `set -e`, the service will error out if `ping` fails or the target *bookmark* does not exist. As I originally wrote this as a `bash` shell *script* for use in Terminal it will require some additional coding to not have Automator error out under those conditions. If either error occurs the Bookmark.plist file is not replaced so there really isn't anything to worry about.

Comment: Wow, this is also a great approach! I like that it updates the URL without having to close Safari and re-open. I was reading about [plistbuddy](https://marcosantadev.com/manage-plist-files-plistbuddy/), which is an Apple provided app for editing plist files. Thought it might be worth mentioning for others researching this. Thank you for taking the time to provide an alternate method, which seems to have it's benefits over AppleScript. Bravo! Someone get this coder a beer!